# Gremlin Tinkerpop returns an object Path, how do you access the individual vertices

Tags: gremlin, tinkerpop, tinkerpop3

I can see this has been asked a few times but i couldn't see an answer that works for me.

I am using this in a Java application and i want to return an ArrayList of either vertices or just of Strings containing the vertex iD. I have to use the Path() step as i need the vertices returned in the correct order, however i get just a List of  having 2 Objects, what seems like the source Vertex as an Object and the whole Path as an Object, I can not manipulate or use the data?

My traversal is:

```
List<Object> routeList;

routeList = g.V(sourceID).shortestPath().with(ShortestPath.edges, Direction.OUT)
                .with(ShortestPath.distance, "weight").with(ShortestPath.target, hasId(targetId))
                .with(ShortestPath.includeEdges, false).path().unfold().toList();
```

The output of the list is:

```
v[L00-041]
path[v[L00-041], v[L00-042], ...etc.... v[L00-043], v[L00-031]]
```

I really need to be returning the path in a usable format. I am sure someone has been in this position before and can help me out. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general for path() queries Gremlin will return a Path object to you that you can iterate through. Here is an example from the Gremlin Console.

```
gremlin> p = g.V(1).out().limit(1).path().next()
==>v[1]
==>v[135]
gremlin> p.class
==>class org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.step.util.ImmutablePath
gremlin> p[1]
==>v[135]
gremlin> p[0]
==>v[1]       
gremlin> p.size()
==>2
gremlin> for (e in p) {println(e)}
v[1]
v[135]
```

The relevant JavaDoc is here:

https://tinkerpop.apache.org/javadocs/current/full/org/apache/tinkerpop/gremlin/process/traversal/step/util/ImmutablePath.html

https://tinkerpop.apache.org/javadocs/current/full/org/apache/tinkerpop/gremlin/process/traversal/Path.html

Using Java you can do something like this.

```
List<Path> p = g.V("1").out().limit(1).path().toList();
p.get(0).forEach(e -> System.out.println(e));
```

However, when working with the shortestPath() step the returned result is a ReferencePath that contains the starting vertex and the path that was walked. You can access it from the console as follows and can also do similar to the example above from Java. Like Path, ReferencePath is iterable.

```
gremlin> routeList.class
==>class org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.structure.util.reference.ReferencePath
gremlin> routeList[0].class
==>class org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.structure.util.reference.ReferenceVertex
gremlin> routeList[1].class
==>class org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.structure.util.reference.ReferencePath
gremlin> for (v in routeList[1]) {println v}
v[3]
v[8]
v[44]
```

Here is the JavaDoc for ReferencePath 
https://tinkerpop.apache.org/javadocs/current/full/org/apache/tinkerpop/gremlin/structure/util/reference/ReferencePath.html

Comment: Hi, thank you for showing me the example, that doesn't seem to work for me - Path routeList;

routeList = g.V(sourceID).shortestPath().with(ShortestPath.edges, Direction.OUT)
                .with(ShortestPath.distance, "weight").with(ShortestPath.target, hasId(targetId))
                .with(ShortestPath.includeEdges, false).path().next(); if i try to iterate through the Path Object, i receive indexoutofbounds saying that Path is only a size of 2. it is still the same issue.

Comment: I will add a simple Java example - can you verify that at least this works for you?

Comment: Note that what your specific query returns is a ReferencePath object so you will need to pull the Path out of that first.

Comment: Yes, For your info when i print out the class and size of the Path i do not get the same as you i get: I/System.out: class org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.structure.util.reference.ReferencePath
I/System.out: 2

Comment: I think we were both on the same wavelength then! do you know how i do that, not to worry i can look up some docs if not?

Comment: Added another example. Sorry for any confusion I mis understood that you had not already pulled the path out from the ReferencePath. Like Path, referencePath is iterable.

Comment: Yes that has done the trick, Perfect i can list the vertices now and use the data. Thank Kelvin you for taking the time to help.